# Kaocha-midje setup

Tags: clojure, midje

We have a load of midje tests setup for Clojure, they currently work with lein midje.

We want to use Kaocha-midje, and then the rest of kaocha, but cannot get any tests to be found using Kaocha.type/midje.

Heres the project.clj add-ins:

```
  :profiles {:dev     {:dependencies [[midje "1.9.9"]
                                  [lambdaisland/kaocha "1.0.861"]
                                  [lambdaisland/kaocha-midje "0.0-5"]}}
  :aliases {"kaocha" ["run" "-m" "kaocha.runner"]}
```

There is also the test.edn file

```
{:tests                           [
                                  {:type :kaocha.type/midje
                                   :id   :midje
                                   :source-paths  ["src"]
                                   :test-paths    ["test/unit/directory/path/example_midje_test.clj"]}
                                  ]
 :kaocha/fail-fast?                  false
 :kaocha/color?                      true
 :kaocha.plugin.randomize/randomize? false
 :kaocha/reporter                    [kaocha.report/dots]
 :kaocha/plugins                     [:kaocha.plugin/randomize
                                     :kaocha.plugin/filter
                                     :kaocha.plugin/capture-output]}
```

example_midje_test.clj is the example from https://github.com/lambdaisland/kaocha-midje/blob/master/test/midjetest/the_test.clj

but I have also tried one of our existing tests, and also tried test/unit so it can find them all, but it gives Spec errors, but none of our tests currently fail.

This is the error output for the test/unit test-path

```
WARNING: No tests were found, make sure :test-paths and :ns-patterns are configured correctly in tests.edn.
```

Comment: Have you tried just using e.g. `"test"` as path? And also make sure, your relative file path from that root matches the namespace (including the munging of the `-`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also posted here https://github.com/lambdaisland/kaocha/issues/230

Which said the midje kaocha is experimental at best and suggested moving to something else.